# Angular navigation problem with the ngOnInit method of the previous page

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have two pages A and B and navigation takes place from page A to page B.
On page B I inserted a button to go back:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
...
this.location.back();
```

Navigation works correctly, but I don't want the ngOnInit method in page A to be invoked again when I go back.
This is the method I use to navigate between the two pages:

```
this.router.navigate(['/pages/page-b', item_id]);
```

**UPDATE:**

I would not want the xxx method to be called because it makes database calls which in this case I would like to avoid

Comment: you could have a look at the [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy)

Comment: Why don't you use sessionStorage/localStorage with a flag visited = 0 || 1

Comment: you can't stop calling ngOnInit. Have some event emitter from page B, based on that handle the inside logic of ngOnInit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing much to be needed here. When you visit the `ngOnInit()` for the first time. You should turn the variable true, by declaring one more variable.

When you come back from page B. In your `ngOnInit()` just check the value of that variable. If its `true`, don't call the method used for api call.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is just to avoid a DB call as mentioned, you can try caching the result in your service

```
class Service {
  private _cachedData;

  public getData() {
    if (this._cachedData)
      return of(this._cachedData);
    return this.http.get('/api')
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => { this._cachedData = res; })
      );
  }
}
```

Make sure to use apt datatypes like dictionary if your api call has parameters